# Hiding/Showing CSS elements does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

[THE WHOLE CODE IN JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wvc0m6os/2/)

I have been struggling to effectively remove the code and css created in the `function Seifenblasen_blasen()`

```
function Seifenblasen_blasen(){
            btn1.style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Bubble"
            const section = document.querySelector('section')
            const createElement = document.createElement('spawn')
            var size = Math.random() * 60;
            createElement.style.width = 30 + size + 'px';
            createElement.style.height = 30 + size + 'px';
            createElement.style.left = Math.random() * innerWidth + "px";
            section.appendChild(createElement);
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                createElement.remove()
            },8000)
            
        }
        const Blaseninterval = setInterval(Seifenblasen_blasen, 100)
```

created CSS:

```
section {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: #1F69FA;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            
        }
section.text{
            font-size: 10em;
            color: #333;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: consolas;
            background-color:#1F69FA;
            pointer-events: none;
            border: none;
            
        }
section spawn {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -80px;
            background: transparent;
            border-radius: 50%;
            pointer-events: none;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
        
        }
section spawn:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transform: scale(0.25) translate(-70%, -70%);
            background: radial-gradient(#fff, transparent);
            opacity: 0.6;
            border-radius: 50%;
            
        }
@keyframes animate {
            0% {
                transform: translateY(0%);
                opacity: 1;
            }
            99% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateY(-2000%);
                opacity: 0;
            }
        section span {
            margin-top: 700px;
            font-size: 1em;
            color: #333;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: consolas;
            background-color: #1F69FA;
            border: none;
            position: absolute;
            
        }
```

HTML:

```
 <section id="section">
        <div class="content">
            <button id="btn"></button>
            <button id="btn1"></button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

to then execute the next function `function next()`. This removal is needed because when I don't remove the elements from the first function the second wont work. I could just do `document.head.innerHTML = ""` but that would then also remove the css needed for the button appearing in the next function. So then I tried to make variables with `const`

```
const btn = document.getElementById('text');
const btn1 = document.getElementById('text1');
const section = document.querySelector('section')
// in function Seifenblasen_blasen()
btn1.style.display = 'none';
// in function next()
section.style.display = 'none';
btn.style.display = 'none';
btn1.style.display = 'block';
```

to hide and show only parts of the css without removing the css entirely to keep the styling intact, but now nothing works anymore.(the button on the next Screen doesn't show up at all and the first button does not contain any styling) My endgoal is that I can essentially switch between two screens one showing the bubbles and one the bouncy balls and when I click on the button it goes on. (for example start is bubbles. I click -> Bounce, click again -> back to Bubbles and so on)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you're working on, so that we can help.

Comment: I edited it maybe it makes more sense now

Comment: If you add the html also, I will solve this for you, and one more time, what you want is to delete all content created by this function Seifenblasen_blasen() ?

Comment: Uploaded HTML. So if you go to my fiddle at the top you can see a kind of working version of it but I came to the conclusion it might be easier to just hide the elements with display none.  [here  my try](https://jsfiddle.net/wvc0m6os/4/) but again I can switch screens on this new one essetially by clicking the text, but on the second screen after clicking once there should be standing "bounce" instead of "bubble". But it doesn't. That would be maybe more helpful for me tbh as hiding the elements and making them visible again really seems promissing.

Comment: BUT if you have a better solution to go about this then feel free to tell me. As I already said my real endgoal is so that when I click the text Bubble it switches screens and it shows the bouncy balls falling and then when I click Bounce it just goes back to the Bubble screen where one can see the bubbles floating and when I click bubble again it switches back to bounce so on and so forth. The deleting was just one thought of doing it as I found out that hiding also works so deleting should not be neccesarry. I think it is rather neccessary to get the Elements off the screen.